# Best model for WPF+MVVM+EF 6.1

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I’m trying to figure out best model for my WPF+MVVM+EF 6.1 application and I’m little confuse how to do this right after watching many EF courses and blogs. When modeling application in WPF there is a need for INotifyPropertyChanged, Observablecollection and also adding some additional calculated properties (not persisted on the database). I’m considering this solutions:

1. Change EF T4 template and implement INotifyPropertyChanged, change collections to Observablecollection and add additional fields in partial class. This brings to bind to EF model but looks simple and easer to maintain;
2. Use separate class for domain objects and rewrite data between them – for instance using automapper. This have separation of concerns but all updated and inserted entities have to be translated to appropriate EF entities.
3. Implement new class that have EF class nested inside new class with all properties wrapped and change tracked – this in other hand brings redundant code.

What will be best solution for this which not involve writing redundant code?

Comment: How about a viewmodel?

Comment: What about ViewModel? The whole question is how to use EF models in ViewModel – When I get model from DB how to sync and bind to it? How To sync data between model and viewModel? Use in directly or use other model and sync it?

Answer (score 1):

How about using the generated EF entities as it is and creating a DTO model that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` **only** when it is necessary.

Not in every case you need to be able to **synchronize** the data between the view and the model right away.

Don't abuse the usage of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It will be too late when you realize that you have **a lot of extra code** that doesn't actually need two way binding, **a lot of repetitive work** and **can't be reused** by other client view (could be an asp.net) because it's too technology specific (for example dependency property).

And the MVVM pattern works fine for a simple data display without you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the binding data.

```
public class Order
{
   public string OrderNo { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
public class WindowViewModel
{
    public WindowViewModel()
    {
        var orders = Service<TheEntity>.Get();
        Array.ForEach(orders, order => Orders.Add(order));
    }

    private readonly ObservableCollection<Order> _orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
    public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders
    {
        get { return _orders; }
    }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new WindowViewModel();
    }
}
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="OrderNo" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OrderNo}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}"/> 
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Comment: If I understand right you are proposing second option from my list? I don’t really understand what this example shows – you load some entities from some service to Observable collection but this entity is not using INotifyPropertyChanged. To be more precise – I have entities from EF named A, B, C, D and E and I would like to operate on them in the ViewModel. If I understand right entities which are read only will be binded directly and editable once should be sync to some ViewModel entity? Is AutoMapper right way to do this? How to sync data between model and videmodel?

Comment: use EF entity as it is, then if it's not possible use second option. that example shows that for a simple view, you don't actually need to implement `inotifypropertychanged`, unless you do a programmatically change in the viewmodel. the changes from UI will be sync-ed without `inotifypropertychanged`, but if you make a change in the vm and want the ui to be updated, then you need that interface. But I still think that option 2 is violating DRY principle.. unless the UI is complex and very custom

Answer (score 0):

The best way is not to disturb auto-generated code from EF, even if you wrap it inside, new class, you still need some mechanism to track and save changes, doing it so completely overrides for what entity framework is designed for (less coding in DAL). The best way is to have properties (observable collection or i notify properties in VM- View Model). You might need to put little more code into your application but that helps you and to maintain the code and it will be total decoupled from other modules (BL, DAL, ..) of the application.

Comment: If I understand right you are proposing to have separate viewmodel class for all CRUD entities and sync data between them when loading or saving data from DB? Is Automaper the best choice for this or maybe some other technique?

Comment: @dnf I used to write my own mapper, as it was small application. You got to check one used in PRISM framework or some other mvvm framework as each one has its own merits/demerits.